# Auto indent in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I want to auto indent my text using Notepad++. Is there a way to do this? Or do I have to install any plugin?

I have tried all I know in Notepad++, but it seems things are not working. I have even used the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, but that works fine in Eclipse, but Notepad++ gives a find textbox instead.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/412427/612253

Answer (score 5):

#### I want to auto indent my text using Notepad++. Is there a way to do this?

You need to enable "Auto-indent".

Prior prior to v7.8.3:

- "Settings" > "Preferences > "MISC." > tick "Auto-indent" then press "Close"

  [image]

Later versions:

- Settings "Settings" > "Preferences > "Auto-Completion" > tick "Auto-indent" then press "Close"

  [image]

Comment: @ThinhNV It has moved to the Auto-Completion settings page

Comment: @Phlucious It has moved to the Auto-Completion settings page

Answer (score 2):

You can use a plugin (IndentByFold).
You can either get it by going to

> Plugins -> Plugins Admin

or from GitHub: [IndentByFold](https://github.com/ffes/indentbyfold/).

Answer (score 0):

I type some code, select it and then use:

menu *TextFX* → *TextFX Edit* → *Reindent C++ code*.

TextFX should be installed by default.

Comment: thanks very much, but I used Plugins > Indent By Fold > Reindent file. There was no need to select a particular portion. It indents the whole file. If notepad++ doesn't have this plugin by default, one will have to download it

Answer (score 0):

Auto-indent stopped working for a bit when I accidentally started recording a macro. I stopped it by clicking the "stop recording" button at the end of the toolbar.